# SQL Grouping: Most recent record between users

Tags: sql, grouping

Maybe I'm having a really bad day, but could someone possibly help me to turn this:

```
MessageID | SendingUserID | ReceivingUserID
-------------------------------------------
1073      | 1002          | 1001
1065      | 1001          | 1002
1076      | 1008          | 1002
```

Into:

```
MessageID | SendingUserID | ReceivingUserID
-------------------------------------------
1073      | 1002          | 1001
1076      | 1008          | 1002
```

Whereby,only the most recent message between two users is listed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT Message.*
FROM Message
WHERE Message.MessageID IN
(SELECT MAX(MessageID) FROM Message 
    GROUP BY 
        CASE WHEN ReceivingUserID > SendingUserID 
            THEN ReceivingUserID ELSE SendingUserID END,
        CASE WHEN ReceivingUserID > SendingUserID
            THEN SendingUserID ELSE ReceivingUserID END
)
```

Comment: updated to match the "between two users" requirement; @unknown: you cannot select SendingUserID without aggregation and without GroupBy

Comment: You can, but the result will be non-deterministic for those columns if they aren't constant within the partition.

Comment: Thanks for your example, it does work, although I'm a little confused by the Casing in the Group By, they both are the same - is that right?

Answer (score 0):

The exclusive self join approach:

```
select *
from YourTable a
left join YourTable b 
    on (
        (a.SendingUserID = b.SendingUserID
        and a.ReceivinggUserID = b.ReceivingUserID)
        or (a.SendingUserID = b.ReceivingUserID
        and a.ReceivinggUserID = b.SendingUserID)
    ) and b.messageid > a.messageid
 where b.messageid is null
```

The join on "b" searches for later messages between the same users.  The WHERE clause filters for messages that do not have a later message.  This gives you only the latest message between each pair of users.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CTE (Common Table Expression) in SQL Server 2005 and higher to make sure the two UserID's are always the smaller one before the larger one, and then just get the maximum for each of those combinations:

```
WITH Messages(MessageID, User1, User2)
AS 
(
    SELECT
        MessageID,
        CASE 
          WHEN SendingUserID < ReceivingUserID
          THEN SendingUserID
          ELSE ReceivingUserID 
        END as 'User1',
        CASE 
          WHEN SendingUserID < ReceivingUserID
          THEN ReceivingUserID 
          ELSE SendingUserID
        END as 'User2'
    FROM 
        MyMessages
)
SELECT 
    MessageID, User1, User2 
FROM 
    Messages m1
WHERE
    MessageID = (SELECT MAX(MessageID) FROM  Messages m2 
                 WHERE m1.User1 = m2.User1 AND m1.User2 = m2.User2)
```

The inner SELECT inside the CTE would "order" your messages like this:

```
MessageID   User1   User2
  1065       1001    1002
  1073       1001    1002
  1076       1002    1008
```

and the outer `SELECT` based on this CTE then just simply picks the entry with the maximum `MessageID` for every combination of (User1, User2).

Marc